# Error adding a new sequence to LaTeX-math-list

Tags: auctex

Could someone help me to figure out what the template to add a new symbol to `LaTeX-math-list` is?

I am trying to extend the available list with two sequences, not exactly symbols; I am not sure if this is possible. So far, I ended up with the following line in `.emacs`

```
(setq LaTeX-math-list '((?\C-w (lambda () "\\Wec\{\}") "" nil)
                        (?\C-v (lambda () "\\Bec\{\}") "" nil)))
```

After enabling math mode, the additional keybindings are visible (with `lambda` at each item) but when I try to run any of them I get the following error:

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, (lambda nil "\\Wec{}")
```

I am currently learning Lisp so this is as far as I could get. Hope this is solvable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *command* is a function containing an `interactive` form and this is, apparently, at `LaTeX-math-list` expects.  So

```
(setq LaTeX-math-list '((?\C-w (lambda () (interactive) "\\Wec\{\}") "" nil)
                        (?\C-v (lambda () (interactive) "\\Bec\{\}") "" nil)))
```

should do the job (but I haven't tested it).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the clue. It's no longer generating error but also doesn't show anything when I press the combination of the keys. Emacs shows it's accepted the keys, though. I don't know if I should ask a new question or edit this one?

Comment: I think a new one is in order.