# AUCTeX does not display custom symbols added to LaTeX-math-list

Tags: auctex

This is a follow up from this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73335/18879), where the previous problem was solved.

I am trying to employ AUCTeX to produce certain sequences, not exactly symbols, when I press key combinations: ` C-w or ` C-v. Below is what I added to `.emacs`

```
(setq LaTeX-math-list '((?\C-w (lambda () "\\Wec\{\}") "" nil)
                        (?\C-v (lambda () "\\Bec\{\}") "" nil)))
```

It doesn't show anything when I try to press the keys. I made sure I was in `LaTeX-mode` as well as `Latex-Math` mode was enabled. I could see Emacs recognises the keys but nothings happens.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this that works like a charm:

```
(setq LaTeX-math-list '((?\C-w "Wec" "" nil)
                        (?\C-v "Bec" "" nil)))
```

You can set it with `customize-variable LaTeX-math-list`.

The doc string of `LaTeX-math-list` says:

> VALUE can be a string with the name of the macro to be inserted,
> or a function to be called. *The macro must be given without the
> leading backslash.*

(Emphasis added).

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I pretty much tried everything but that simple name and then I read backlash is added .For the purpose of understanding better, can you tell why my version didn't work?

Comment: Also, is it possible if I add braces `{}` to hold a cursor inside or that would be too complicated?

Comment: You had a leading backslash in the value: you are supposed to give the name of the macro *without* a leading backslash.